# Are These Pliers Bad?

Tags: tools

Does anyone have a Southwire lineman's 9 inch side cutting plier? Is it supposed to have that much of a gap or do I have a bad set of pliers?

This is how big the gap is when it is closed completely.

[image: Southwire lineman's 9 inch side cutting pliers]

Comment: I believe my snap on have a slight gap and I hate them, one of these days I will remember to exchange them. Those look like seconds with the chip at the top left or that’s what I thought.

Comment: A gap in the cutters would be a problem.   A gap on the grips is not unless it is wider than what you are gripping.

Comment: I have a pair of Bostitch linesman pliers with the exact same gap. It's done on purpose so that the cutters can do their job. I've been able to grip 26 gauge sheet metal with mine so if you encounter something too small to be gripped then you probably shouldn't be using linesman pliers for the task :)

Comment: That is a feature, not a flaw lol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are actually called side cutting pliers. The gap at the top is supposed to be there to allow the cutting edges to do their job. I have a pair of Kleins with the exact same gap.... except for a 5/32" hole in the cutters from cutting a live wire.... in my younger years.

Comment: I lent my brand-new side cutters to a mate who promptly cut a live wire - two matching holes in the cutters...

Comment: I've had a hole in my Kleins for 25 years - my BIL _assured_ me the power was off. :(

Comment: @FreeMan  I had a helper who wanted to get some tools. I directed him to my electric supply store and told him to make sure he got the Klein's  with the hole in the cutters.... told him it was for stripping #14.... the sales people there are probably still laughing...

Comment: There are other advantages to the gap.  Better grip on wire (of 14 guage or larger) and T&B Marettes.  Less marring and it aids in establishing and forming a nice helical twist.

Comment: If you check out Klein rebar pliers, they have all the same features (Offset hinge, crosshatched gapped grip), except the width of crosshatch and gap are tailored to the materials they work with and they have a head designed to lever.